# Toast in fragmentadapter in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-toast

I have this problem i cant toast in the fragment adapter i've tried getActivity and its not working any suggestions why?

```
public class SamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            /** Show a Fragment based on the position of the current screen */
            if (position == 0) {
                return new SampleFragment();}
            if (position == 1) {
                    return new SampleFragment1q();
            } else
                return new SampleFragmentTwo();
            Toast.makeText(TSlide.this,  "end of lesson" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can receive a Context as argument that is enabled to post Toasts.

BUT, you will have a big problem in toasting at getItem(int), since it can be instantiated BEFORE being show you will probably see your toast one screen before the one you intended to. Also, if the Adapter doesn't destroy the item, you will not get this method called again.

A better solution is to addOnPageChangedListener in the ViewPager and rely on the position at onPageSelected to display a Toast of the current visible page.